# Atomic Compare And Swap with struct in Go

Tags: struct, queue, go, compare-and-swap

I am trying to create a non-blocking queue package for concurrent application using the algorithm by Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott as described [here](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/research/synchronization/pseudocode/queues.html#nbq).

This requires the use of atomic CompareAndSwap which is offered by the `"sync/atomic"` package.
I am however not sure what the Go-equivalent to the following pseudocode would be:

```
E9:   if CAS(&tail.ptr->next, next, <node, next.count+1>)
```

where `tail` and `next` is of type:

```
type pointer_t struct {
    ptr   *node_t
    count uint
}
```

and `node` is of type:

```
type node_t struct {
    value interface{}
    next  pointer_t
}
```

If I understood it correctly, it seems that I need to do a CAS with a struct (both a pointer and a `uint`). Is this even possible with the `atomic`-package?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If I understood it correctly, it seems that I need to do a CAS with a struct (both a > pointer and a uint). Is this even possible with the atomic-package?

No, that is not possible. Most architectures only support atomic operations on a single word. A lot of academic papers however use more powerful CAS statements (e.g. compare and swap double) that are not available today. Luckily there are a few tricks that are commonly used in such situations:

- You could for example steal a couple of bits from the pointer (especially on 64bit systems) and use them, to encode your counter. Then you could simply use Go's CompareAndSwapPointer, but you need to mask the relevant bits of the pointer before you try to dereference it.
- The other possibility is to work with pointers to your (immutable!) pointer_t struct. Whenever you want to modify an element from your pointer_t struct, you would have to create a copy, modify the copy and atomically replace the pointer to your struct. This idiom is called COW (copy on write) and works with arbitrary large structures. If you want to use this technique, you would have to change the next attribute to `next  *pointer_t`.

I have recently written a lock-free list in Go for educational reasons. You can find the (imho well documented) source here: https://github.com/tux21b/goco/blob/master/list.go

This rather short example uses [atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#CompareAndSwapPointer) excessively and also introduces an atomic type for marked pointers (the MarkAndRef struct). This type is **very similar** to your pointer_t struct (except that it stores a bool+pointer instead of an int+pointer). It's used to ensure that a node has not been marked as deleted while you are trying to insert an element directly afterwards. Feel free to use this source as starting point for your own projects.

Comment: Thanks tux! Yes, my package is also for educational reason, and I can't say that I have much experience with lock-free coding. But your package helps learning. I will, however, wait to see if I might get an answer which might be more specific to the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I have now tried to answer your question more precisely. Feel free to ask if I have missed something again :)

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks for adding to the answer. It helps me understand what is possible and what is the limits of atomic operation. Naah, now I feel your answer has both answered my question and given me some extra information useful for my project.

Comment: Why not avoid the additional indirection by making the node_t struct the immutable object and using CAS to update the ptr field in pointer_t?

Comment: @Matt: That won't work. Suppose you have a linked list with three node_t structs A -> B -> C. If you want to append a new node D at the end of the list, you would have to create a new node_t for C, and change B.next atomically. Unfortunately there is no guarantee, that B is still part of the list. A.next might already point to C directly if someone has decided to remove B. This problem is solved by the separate markAndRef struct.

Comment: To clarify:
`type node_t struct{value interface{}; ptr *node_t; count uint}`
...
`atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&tail, next, node_t{value, next, next.count+1})`
 - `tail` and `next` would both be of type `*node_t`.

Comment: I know, I was assuming a similar layout, except that I don't assumed a tail pointer (just head). Anyway, even if you manage to introduce such a tail pointer, the problem will stay the same if you try to insert something in the middle (i.e. after a node that could be removed) of the list.

Comment: Actually node_t wouldn't be completely immutable; just the ptr field could be modified. In your example you wouldn't create a new node_t for C; you would modify C.ptr using CAS. B would continue to point to C. CAS(&tail.ptr, nil, node_t{value, nil, 0}). Unfortunately I think we lose an important attribute of the original algorithm - only a single allocation is made for each enqueue call.
I think the Go way to do this would be to use a couple of channels plus a goroutine to manage the linked list. "Share memory by communicating - don't communicate by sharing memory".

Comment: Hmm. The count field could still be modified in the new tail *until* it is inserted into the list. So we could avoid allocation in the loop of enqueue().

Comment: The original algorithm also uses at least two allocations per enqueue call (node_t and markAndRef). Also, I still don't understand what you have in mind. If you want to insert a new node D, you can't simply change C.ptr, because C.deleted / C.counter might change at the same time, and your inserted item will be lost. You can't replace the full C node because of similar reasons (deleting B). Go's channels are great and easy to understand, but they are not lock-free / block-free and they do quite a lot of expensive work in the background. Therefore those data structures are still useful in Go.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
 if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(
    (*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(tail.ptr.next)), 
    unsafe.Pointer(&next), 
    unsafe.Pointer(&pointer_t{&node, next.count + 1})
 )
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but since `next` is `var pointer_t` and not `var *pointer_t` it is not possible to convert. Nor does `node_t` have properties `node` and `count`. .. but I admit I don't understand why the pseudocode says `<node, next.count+1>`